# Calling/Implementing a function from another program

Tags: c

I have been attempting to get this problem right for so long and I have found that the part that I am most confused about is the part where I am supposed to use functions that have already been defined and made in another program, but a program that I am supposed to attach unchanged to my new program (sorry if that doesn't make sense). But here is the program with the functions that have already been defined that we are suppose to use in our program unchanged:

```
#ifndef COMMON_H
#define COMMON_H
#include <stdlib.h>

/* constants: number of different characters, and
              first and last printable characters */
#define NUM 128
#define FIRST '!'
#define LAST '~'

/* symbols for special characters, corresponding to codes 0 through FIRST-1 */ char *symbols[] = {"NUL", "SOH", "STX", "ETX", "EOT", "ENQ", "ACK",
    "BEL", "BS", "HT", "LF", "VT", "FF", "CR", "SO", "SI", "DLE", "DC1",
    "DC2", "DC3", "DC4", "NAK", "SYN", "ETB", "CAN", "EM", "SUB", "ESC",
    "FS", "GS", "RS", "US", "SPC" };

/* symbol for DEL character, code LAST+1 (same as NUM-1) */ char
*symbolDel = "DEL";

/* the following four functions must be used to print results */

/* use prHeader at the start to print header row (titles) */ void prHeader(FILE *out) {
    fprintf(out, "Code\tChar\tCount\n----\t----\t-----\n"); }

/* use prCountStr to print count for one of the special symbols */ void prCountStr(FILE *out, int code, char *str, int count) {
    fprintf(out, "%3d\t%s\t%5d\n", code, str, count); }

/* use prCountChr to print count for one of the printable characters
*/ void prCountChr(FILE *out, int code, char chr, int count) {
    fprintf(out, "%3d\t%c\t%5d\n", code, chr, count); }

/* use prTotal at the end to print total character count */ void prTotal(FILE *out, int count) {
    fprintf(out, "\t\t-----\nTotal\t\t%5d\n", count); }

/* use the following three macros to print error messages for part 2   {
       Beware: each macro executes two statements.    }    ignore these macros for part 1 */

/* use BADFILE(name) to exit if a file (name) cannot be opened */
#define BADFILE(name) fprintf(stderr, "bad file: %s\n", (name)); \
                      exit(1);

/* use BADOPTION(op) if an invalid option (not '-o') is on command line */
#define BADOPTION(op) fprintf(stderr, "bad option: %s\n", (op)); \
                      exit(2);

/* use MISSING (without parens) if output filename is missing */
#define MISSING fprintf(stderr, "missing output file\n"); \
                      exit(3);


#endif
```

And using these definitions I am supposed to after receiving the input, print a table as so, that shows the character, the ASCII representation, and how many times that character occurred like this example:

```
Code    Char    Count
----    ----    -----
 10         LF      3
 32        SPC     35
 40         (       1
 41         )       1
 45         -       1
 46         .       4
 58         :       1
 68         D       1
 72         H       2
 73         I       4
 79         O       1
 84         T       1
```

EDITED CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "common.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  FILE *in = stdin;
  FILE *out = stdout;
  int x;
  int count1 = 0;
  int count2 = 0;
  int asciicount[256] = {0};

 do
  {
      x = getchar();
      asciicount[x]++;
      count1++;
  } while (x != EOF);

 for (count2; count2<=255; count2++)
   {
     if (count2<33)
       {
         prCountStr(out, count2, symbols[count2], asciicount[count2]);
       }
     else
       {
         prCountChr(out,count2,x,asciicount[count2]);
       }
   }
     prTotal(out, count1);
     prHeader(out);
     return 0;
   }
 /* do                                                                         
  {                                                                            
      if (count2 < '!')                                                        
      {                                                                        
        prCountStr(out, count2, symbols[count2], asciicount[count2]);          
      }                                                                        
      else{                                                                    
      prCountChr(out,count2,x,asciicount[count2]);                             
      }                                                                        
      count2++;                                                                
   } while (count2 <= 255);                                                    
  prTotal(out, count1);                                                        

  prHeader(out);                                                               
  return 0;                                                                    
  }*/
```

The second part is what I had before but I am commenting out and trying a for loop to see whether that could fix the problem.
Here is the new output, it is printing this all the way to 255 without counting how many times each occurs or printing the ascii code.

```
 29 GS      0
 30 RS      0
 31 US      0
 32 SPC     0
 33 ?       0
 34 ?       0
 35 ?       0
 36 ?       0
 37 ?       0
 38 ?       0
 39 ?       0
 40 ?       0
 41 ?       0
 42 ?       0
```

Comment: You might want to check e.g. [this reference for `printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf), because I think you use the returned value from `printf` wrongly.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea. But there are several syntax errors in your code.

- You need to `#include <stdio.h>` because the definitions of FILE, printf, etc are there.
- `x` is meant to be a `char`, so you should define it as such. I see that you have commented `int x;`. You should have `char x;` instead.
- The proper syntax for `do-while` loops is (notice the semicolon at the end of while):

  ```
  do {
     //statements
  } while (condition);
  ```
- `r` is not defined.
- Because your `if` statement ends in `;`, the `prCountStr` statement will always be executed, and you will get a syntax error on the `else` right after.
- You only need to include the type of a variable (`int`, `char`, etc) in the function's definition, not in the function's call. For instance, a proper way to call `prCountStr` would be

  ```
  prCountStr(out, someInt, somePointerToChar, someInt);
  ```
- You need to give a function as many arguments as it requires on its definition. This applies to your calls to `prCountChr` and `prTotal`, where you are passing `void` as a parameter, but they require `FILE *out, int code, char chr, int count` and `FILE *out, int count` respectively.

I had included a quick analysis of the algorithm you used and a proposed solution in my original answer but realized that is not what you were asking for. If you need any further clarifications, let me know

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. Okay so are my variables defined in a way that they would execute correctly in the prCountStr ect functions. As in for the variables I defined     FILE *in = stdin;
    FILE *out = stdout;
    /*int x;*/
    int count1 = 0;
    int count2 = 0;
    int asciicount[256] = {0}; do they fit correctly in order to execute the program, or do I need to redefine them, (already redefined x to a char). And I am unclear with exactly would go in the File *out slot.

Comment: @CordeliaWilliams Your variables are well defined. In the `FILE *out` slot you need to enter only `out`, since it is consistent with your definition. 
For instance, say you want to call prCountChr. One option would be to call it as `prCountStr(out, count2, symbols[count2], asciicount[count2])`

Comment: Worlds clearer at this point. Last question hopefully has to do with my use of printf, I am trying to make it so prCountStr is used for each row that corresponds to a special character (codes 0-32, and 127), so I tried to create an if statement that does that, but apparently printf cannot be used in that way. So my if/else statement doesnt make sense, but I am not sure of another way to make it go to 1 function if the ascii codes is within those bounds, and to the other one otherwise. Im hoping do while will accomplish my goal for he at least total, but i dont think in can for the other ones.

Comment: @CordeliaWilliams Remember that you are looping through your codes with the variable `count2`. It goes from 0 to 255. An `if` statement is the right idea, but the print statement should be outside the if.
You want to test something like `if (count2 < '!') { prCountStr(..... ) } else { prCountChr .... `.
And you should probably add a special case for 'DEL'

Comment: Thanks again. I am still getting the same two errors though. One says expected ‘while’ at end of input when I followed your instruction on while loop format exactly for both do-while loops and the other error says 'symbol' undeclared (first use in the function), (prCountStr(out, count2, *symbol[count2], asciicount[count2])) when symbols is declared in the helper program that I am using at the beginning of the program. And then expected declaration or statement at the end of input. I don't know whats going with these last few errors on but I've really gotten a lot from your help thus far!

Comment: I'm not really sure about the first error. Hard to tell without looking at the modified code, but it seems to be a simple syntax mistake. Just make sure that you are implementing both do-while loops properly. You can look online for examples on how to implement them.
For the other error, the name of the variable is actually symbols, not symbol. Also, you shouldn't dereference it. *symbols[count2] is actually a char, not a char*. Just pass the parameter as symbols[count].

Comment: No problem. Youtube is a great help when learning on without a class. I have managed to get rid of all the errors, but it is not printing correctly in the least. I edited the above with my new code and the output, I am playing around with a for loop now to see if I can figure it out that way, but Im obtaining the same results. I think my iterator and counting variables are incorrect in the way I used them.

Comment: @CordeliaWilliams The useful scope of your x variable is limited to your first do-while loop. At any point after that, the value of X will be EOF. If you see the parameters that you need to pass to prCountChr, they are a File pointer, the code, the char, and the count. But in C (and many other languages), a char is really an integer. So the code and the char are really the same thing in this case.